# Custom Docker Swarm Scheduler

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I would like to use Docker Swarm to run different Docker containers - but I would like to implement a custom scheduler, as features of the build in schedulers seem to be limited.

How can I create, and install a custom scheduler?

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: If I were you, to start, I would go through [these files](https://github.com/docker/swarm/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=strategy)