# Custom orchestration strategy for Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I was looking to use Docker's swarm mode as a distributed container orchestration solution but using custom orchestration strategies/algorithms. Using the official nomenclature, what I want to modify is the [scheduler](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/blob/master/design/nomenclature.md#scheduler). Is this possible? Does Docker offer any kind of hook/plugin system to define your own algorithms?

NOTE: I've found [this question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598621/custom-docker-swarm-scheduler) that asks the same question about the old Docker Swarm (standalone) but the only link offered does not apply to the new Docker swarm mode.